# Bot Framework Intermittent Connection

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I'm struggling to troubleshoot a problem with my chatbot. It is a locally deployed bot with external connections to Azure for LUIS and QnA Maker. One of the LUIS apps is dispatch. I was working on my QnA pairs and responses, not in the bot code at all, and the bot started returning only the default "I'm still learning" error response to any input. Since then it has had intermittent instances where it works like normal again, but then returns to the error response for all input. I've tried refreshing the app pool and restarting the app in IIS, but neither of those get it to work again. There is nothing that I do to bring it back except wait and try it again periodically. Luis.ai and qnamaker.ai are working normally and don't indicate any problems. If Azure portal indicates any problem, I haven't found where that is indicated. I've checked all my endpoint and appid strings and nothing has changed for those. I don't know if it is related, but the emulator no longer works when I try to run the bot from Visual Studio. I would appreciate any help in getting me pointed in the right direction to try to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you follow any specific documentation for this setup? Other than testing it on the emulator, have you tested your bot on any of the channels on Azure? You can check for the issues in the Channels tab under Bot management on Azure.

Comment: I have tested the bot through Azure and get the same errors. I found that my Application Insights were improperly connected, so I'm getting a bit more information now. They indicate an issue connecting to LUIS, but those keys are all confirmed. My current line of investigation is in the framework itself. I'm not sure how to confirm, but I suspect the initial build may have been based on version 0.8-beta.

Comment: One last update: I was also using the authoring key instead of the prediction key for my LUIS connection. There is a limit of 1000 predictions on the authoring key, so that may have been the problem.